# Remove elements from SVG by id, using XSL

Tags: xml, bash, xslt, svg

I am in need of a bash script that would process and edit a PDF file.

I have successfuly converted the PDF file to SVG, and am now trying to remove stuff I don't need from this SVG.

Here is a sample of the file I want to edit :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="595pt" height="842pt" viewBox="0 0 595 842" version="1.1">
<defs>
<g>
<symbol overflow="visible" id="glyph0-0">
<path style="stroke:none;" d=""/>
</symbol>
<symbol overflow="visible" id="glyph0-1">
<path style="stroke:none;" d=""/>
</symbol>
<symbol overflow="visible" id="glyph0-2">
<path style="stroke:none;" d="M 4.90625 -5.71875 C 4.453125 -6.171875 3.953125 -6.359375 3.296875 -6.359375 -5.71875 "/>
</symbol>
<symbol overflow="visible" id="glyph1-1">
<path style="stroke:none;" d="M 3.859375 -7.34375 L 1.625 -6.640625 C 1.4375 -6.59375 1.375 -6.515625 1.375 -6.390625"/>
</symbol>
</g>
</defs>
</svg>
```

I want to delete all "symbol" nodes where id starts with "glyph0", meaning that I would get the following output :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="595pt" height="842pt" viewBox="0 0 595 842" version="1.1">
<defs>
<g>
<symbol overflow="visible" id="glyph1-1">
<path style="stroke:none;" d="M 3.859375 -7.34375 L 1.625 -6.640625 C 1.4375 -6.59375 1.375 -6.515625 1.375 -6.390625"/>
</symbol>
</g>
</defs>
</svg>
```

I have tried using the following xsl file, to remove the glyph0-0 entrance (at first) :

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="svg/defs/g/symbol[id='glyph0-0']"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When I apply this filter using xsltproc, it does nothing. It was meant to remove glyph0-0 :

```
$xsltproc test-3.xsl test.svg | head 
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="595pt" height="842pt" viewBox="0 0 595 842" version="1.1">
<defs>
<g>
<symbol overflow="visible" id="glyph0-0">
<path style="stroke:none;" d=""/>
</symbol>
<symbol overflow="visible" id="glyph0-1">
<path style="stroke:none;" d=""/>
</symbol>
```

I have tried even with shortest matches, such as match="svg/defs/g/symbol", or even match="symbol", and it still does not modify the svg file.

Is there a way to remove all the "glyph0-*" symbols, using a XML tool (or a bash script, if that's easier) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to delete all "symbol" nodes where id starts with "glyph0"

For this, you need to change:

```
<xsl:template match="svg/defs/g/symbol[id='glyph0-0']"/>
```

to:

```
<xsl:template match="svg:symbol[starts-with(@id,'glyph0-')]" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"/>
```

Comment: That's impressive and solves a problem, I tried to solve for hours. If I have a lot of nodes to handle, isn't there a way to get rid of the boilerplate?

Comment: @userunknown Not sure what you mean by "boilerplate".

Comment: Well, the "svg:symbol" instead of just "symbol" and the "xmlns:svg..."-part. Can't this be specified once, filewide? I'm sorry, I'm not deep in the xml/xslt topic. Probably a very stupid question.

Comment: The ***declaration*** `xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"` can be specified once at the topmost `xsl:stylesheet` element (or any ancestor element). The ***prefix*** `svg:` must be used as part of the name of any element in the SVG namespace (you can use any prefix you like). -- In XSLT 2.0, you can define a default XPath namespace and dispense with the prefix.